# Meaning of 'some' in the sentence below

Tags: meaning

here is the sentence:

> The Taklimakan Desert, second in size to Africa Sahara Desert,
> occupies **some** 337,600 square kilometers of northwestern China.

Can you please give some more example of similar usage of word 'some'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used like that, "some" simply means "approximately" or "about". Examples:

> There are some 8 billion people alive today.

> He must have drunk some 12 to 15 beers before he moved onto the vodka.

> It was some weeks--maybe even a month or more--before she could bring herself to even look at him.